# Is the Poincaré gauge theory a real gauge theory in the mathematical sense?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, gauge-theory

First, I want to say that I posted this in the physics forum but no one seems to be interested to respond so because I really believe that my question can be figured out by mathematicians Am here.

When studying Poincaré gauge theory using Milutin Blagojevich's book on "Gravitation and gauge symmetries" we find an interesting line of thought. But to get that I need to set some equations first.

When doing the Poincaré gauge theory, i.e. taking global transformations making them local and doing the Gauge procedure by adding new fields we find The rotational gauge field $A^{ij}_{\ \ \ \ \mu}$ and the translational gauge field $h_k^{\ \ \mu}$.

The consistency of the theory needs to be maintained by imposing a certain variation on the gauge fields
$$\delta h_{k}{}^{\mu}=w_{k}{}^{i} h_{i}{ }^{\mu}-\xi^{\nu} \partial_{v} h_{k}{}^{\mu}+h_{k}{ }^{v} \partial_{\nu} \xi^{ \mu}$$
and
$$\delta A^{i j}{}_{\mu}=-\partial_{\mu} w^{i j}+A_{k}{}^{j}{}_{\mu} w^{i k}+A^{i}{}_{k\mu} w^{jk}-\left(\partial_{\mu} \xi^{\nu}\right) A^{i j}{}_{\nu}-\xi^{\nu} \partial_{\nu} A^{i j}{}_{\mu}$$

These relations will maintain the Lagrangian invariant even when passing to local transformations.

On the other hand, in a more mathematical way in the book he says

> It is an intriguing fact that PGT does not have the structure of an ‘ordinary’
> gauge theory (McDowell and Mansouri 1977, Regge 1986, Banados et al 1996).
> To clarify this point, we start from the Poincaré generators $P_a$, $M_{ab}$ satisfying the
> Lie algebra (2.6), and define the gauge potential as $A_\mu=e^a{}_\mu P_a + \frac{1}{2} \omega^{ab}{}_\mu M_{ab}$. The infinitesimal gauge transformation $$\delta_{0} A_{\mu}=-\nabla_{\mu} \lambda=-\partial_{\mu} \lambda-\left[A_{\mu}, \lambda\right]$$ where $\lambda=\lambda^{a} P_{a}+\frac{1}{2} \lambda^{a b} M_{a b}$, has the following component content:\begin{aligned}
> \text { Translations: } & \delta_{0} e^{a}{ }_{\mu}=-\nabla_{\mu}^{\prime} \lambda^{a} & & \delta_{0} \omega^{a b}{}_{\mu}=0 \\
> \text { Rotations: } & \delta_{0} e^{a}{ }_{\mu}=\lambda^{a}{}_b e^{b}{ }_{\mu} & & \delta_{0} \omega^{a b}{ }_{\mu}=-\nabla_{\mu}^{\prime} \lambda^{a b}
> \end{aligned} where $\nabla' = \nabla(\omega)$ is the covariant derivative with respect to the spin connection
> $\omega$. The resulting gauge transformations are clearly different from those obtained
> in PGT.

I have questions about this result:

1. how did he get this infinitesimal gauge transformation $\delta_{0} A_{\mu}=-\nabla_{\mu} \lambda=-\partial_{\mu} \lambda-\left[A_{\mu}, \lambda\right]$?
2. maybe this one is related to the first but what is $\lambda$, and what's the point of it?
3. and last, how did he get these gauge field transformations and why are they separated into two parts translations and rotations?

It's difficult for me to explicit all the mathematical framework and all the gauge procedure of this subject. But if my post needs more clarity I will make changes so you can understand more.

Comment: what do you mean by "real gauge theory in the mathematical sense"?

Comment: Like I said in the description of the problem the Poincaré gauge theory can be constructed by the gauge principle as Yang-Mills (Weyl) did back then. This can be named a gauge theory in the physical sense. A gauge theory in the mathematical sense is a theory constructed by what am trying to figure out in my question above.

Comment: In 3-dimensions, the answer is definitely yes, since 3d gravity is equivalent to "topological BF" theory, which a gauge theory defined using some principal $G$-bundle $P$ over a manifold $\mathcal{M}$, defined by the action $S[A,B]:=\int_{\mathcal{M}}\mathrm{tr}(B\wedge F[A])$ where $B$ is a $\mathrm{Ad}(P)$-valued $1$-form and where $F[A]\in\Omega^{2}(\mathcal{M},\mathrm{Ad}(P))$ denotes the curvature of a connection $1$-form on $\mathcal{M}$. ($Ad(P):=P\times_{\mathrm{Ad}}\mathfrak{g}$ denotes the adjoint bundle).

Comment: In higher dimensions, something like this is also true, when introducing certain constraints (so-called "simplicity constraints"), which has to be expected, since gravity in $d>3$ dimensions is not a topological field theory. However, note that one should be careful about the terminology "gauge theory" in this case. (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gauge+theory#gravity_as_a_nongauge_theory)

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking. If this is what you are looking for, then I can provide more details as an answer.

Comment: @G. Blaickner I find really interesting what you said. I had some time to read about this BF theory using topology to construct a field theory and in this case a theory of gravity. But my question was more a technical one it was : we physicians see a gauge transformation as a transformation that keeps a lagrangian symmetrical when transforming locally a fields, but I was wondering why mathematician just define this transformation like that? $\delta_0 A_\mu= ...$

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a bit late, but I think you can relevant details in Hamilton's Mathematical Gauge theory book and the references therein. I post the quote, which is relevant for the discussion:
[image]

**References**: Mark J.D. Hamilton, Mathematical Gauge Theory With Applications To The Standard Model of Particle Physics, Springer.